# What to do when deja-dup restore failed?

Tags: 18.04, deja-dup, duplicity

I have a full backup done by deja-dup in a external HD of about 300Gb.

I'm trying to restore it into another 1tb external HD, but when 58Gb was extracted an error have occurred :(

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1555, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1541, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1393, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1472, in do_backup
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 728, in restore
    restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 560, in Write_ROPaths
    ITR(ropath.index, ropath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/lazy.py", line 344, in __call__
    last_branch.fast_process, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/robust.py", line 38, in check_common_error
    return function(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 614, in fast_process
    ropath.copy(self.base_path.new_index(index))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 445, in copy
    other.writefileobj(self.open("rb"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 627, in writefileobj
    buf = fin.read(_copy_blocksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 212, in read
    if not self.addtobuffer():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 237, in addtobuffer
    self.tarinfo_list[0] = self.tar_iter.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 344, in next
    self.set_tarfile()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 333, in set_tarfile
    self.current_fp = self.fileobj_iter.next()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 764, in get_fileobj_iter
    backup_set.volume_name_dict[vol_num],
 KeyError: 391
```

Anyone knows anything about this kind of error ?

Would be possible to retry the restore but starting where it stopped before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After have passed many days of suffering and have called duplicity + deja-dup on zillion of bad names, I finally recovered my important data.

In order to do that I had to:

- pray to every existent saint :D
- created a text file containing all backup-ed files in the external disk using `duplicity list-current-files file:///media/user/sdb > files.txt`;
- used nautilus to create all the most important directories one by one by hand extracted from the list above;
- then selected each of those directories one by one in nautilus and called `Revert to Previous Version`; This called deja-dup that did its job.

Then I was able to restore all my needed files without duplicity to crash before to end :)

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are missing a volume.

try to add the parameter '--ignore-errors' to the duplicity call, and monitor the output for files not restorable. ..ede/duply.net

from the [duplicity man page](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html)

> --ignore-errors
>
> Try to ignore certain errors if they happen. This option is only intended to allow the restoration of a backup in the face of certain problems that would otherwise cause the backup to fail. It is not ever recommended to use this option unless you have a situation where you are trying to restore from backup and it is failing because of an issue which you want duplicity to ignore. Even then, depending on the issue, this option may not have an effect.
>
> Please note that while ignored errors will be logged, there will be no summary at the end of the operation to tell you what was ignored, if anything. If this is used for emergency restoration of data, it is recommended that you run the backup in such a way that you can revisit the backup log (look for lines containing the string IGNORED_ERROR).
>
> If you ever have to use this option for reasons that are not understood or understood but not your own responsibility, please contact duplicity maintainers. The need to use this option under production circumstances would normally be considered a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately I already did that. Also tried to use --force, but no luck. Duplicity took 8hours to extract 58Gb and still left the most important files to me.